# How do I get MS Outlook to accept the CSS style display:block?

Tags: css, outlook, outlook-2010

I am composing an HTML email using a service (MailChimp). The way that MailChimp marks up headings is to use a `SPAN` tag and gives the tag the inline style of `display:block`.

MS Outlook 2010 ignores this style. I cannot find any work around. Thus, headings wrap, breaking the desired page display.

Yes, I know that Outlook uses MS Word to display HTML.

**Assume that I cannot intervene and hand edit the markup.**

How do I get MS Outlook to accept the CSS style `display:block` and display a `SPAN` tag as a block level element?

Comment: Use a `div` or `p` tag instead?

Comment: You don't have control over how Outlook renders HTML styling. You need to fix the HTML source to make it Outlook-compatible.

Comment: What are you trying to make it look like? Outlook doesn't do anything with the 'display' attribute, but you can work around it with tables.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you can't actually change the HTML. Why is that?

Comment: Blowski - I am setting up a template to hand off to a MailChimp user, so it's best of they don't hand edit HTML.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The CSS `display` attribute is not supported in this version of MS Outlook.

Here's "The Book" on what you can and cannot use:

[campaignmonitor.com/css/](http://campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Basically, if you can't change your mark-up to a *natively*-block item, you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to do it the old fashion way unfortunately. =[ Use tables over tables. so tables=blocks.

Comment: I'm using tables for structure. The markup is coming from the WYSIWYG editor, where no tables are available. Again, assume that i cannot intervene and hand edit the markup.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in this exact situation: needing to create header styles that displayed correctly in outlook without the ability to edit the HTML because I'm handing the template off to a client.

I imagine you've already solved this, but to anyone else who spent several hours trying to answer this question and stumbles across this thread, here's how I fixed it:

1. Delete Mailchimp's default H1, H2, etc.
2. Create your own header styles (I named them Header, Sub-Header, etc. just to avoid confusion)
3. Use the new header styles as you wish. The new headings display as blocks.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on under the hood as I can't inspect in Outlook, but my guess is that by not using the default styles either Mailchimp wraps the header text in divs instead of spans.

Comment: Can you explain how you do step no. 2. I know how to style a tag in the MC-code editor but don't know to add a new tag or how to replace one with another.